# Await when calling 2 function in node js not returning expected value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an exec function that calls 2 other functions and await both of them before resolving, but the getData return values and the convertToArray return undefined. When I call the convertToArray function then the getData function, then the convertToArray return values, and the getData function return undefined.

The exec function:

```
function exec(resultset) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      var getdata = await getData(resultset);
      var convertdoarray = await convertToArray(resultset);
      resolve(convertdoarray);
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}
```

The getData function:

```
function getData(resultset) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resultset.toObjectIter((err, rs) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      var rowIter = rs.rows;
      var rows = [];
      var row = rowIter.next();
      while (!row.done) {
        rows.push(row.value);
        row = rowIter.next();
      }
      rs.rows = rows;
      console.log(rows.length);
      resolve(rows);
    });
  });
}
```

The convertToArray function:

```
function convertToArray(resultset) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      resultset.toObjArray(function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
          return err;
        } else {
          //Returning the result
          resolve(results);
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
      return err;
    }
  });
}
```

How i call the exec function:

```
exports.gues = async function () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const results = await exec(resultset)
                        .then((e) => {
                          resolve(e);
                          return;
                        })
                        .catch((err) => reject(err));
 });
}
```

I am expecting that when both function is called in the exec function, it awaits 1 function, get the expected value then call the 2nd function, get the expected value and then return.

Also, I want when I call the exec function if the exec function takes more than 2 minutes, it returns an error.

Comment: 1. What is `e` here `resolve(e)`? 2. Remove this: `.then((e) => {
                          resolve(e);
                          return;
                        })` 3. What is `rs` here `rs.rows = rows;` 4. Why do you name your result with the same name as the function `var getData = await getData(resultset)`?

Comment: I have updated the resolve from e to converttoarray. It was a typing mistakes

Comment: Could you please confirm if you are using the  [JSBC wrapper for node](https://npmdoc.github.io/node-npmdoc-jdbc/build/apidoc.html) package? Either way please include package information in the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `return` instead of `resolve`:

```js
const results=await exec(resultset)
  .then((e) => e)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Comment: It does not resolve the problem.

Comment: I suggest having a look at what the `gues` function does _or doesn't do_ other than chaining a its returned promise to the promise returned from `exec`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming use of this [JSBC wrapper for node](https://npmdoc.github.io/node-npmdoc-jdbc/build/apidoc.html), you might only need [`function jdbc.resultset.prototype.toObjArray (callback)`](https://npmdoc.github.io/node-npmdoc-jdbc/build/apidoc.html#apidoc.element.jdbc.resultset.prototype.toObjArray) to get an array of row values. If so you could try something like

```js
exports.gues = function( resultset) {
   return Promise.race(
       new Promise( (resolve, reject) => 
           resultset.toObjArray( ( _, rows) => resolve(rows) )
       ),
       new Promise( (resolve, reject) =>
           setTimer( 
               () => reject( Error("Timeout getting resultset rows")),
               2*60*1000
           )
       )
   );
}
```

to get a promise for the row values with a 2 minute timeout.

---

**Will the timeout ever fire?**

If you are using NPM package [jdbc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jdbc) for resultset processing, my major concern is that it uses synchronous I/O - the `next` method in the iterator calls  `self._rs.nextSync();` where `Sync` usually implies synchronous execution.

If resultset methods are synchronous, then they probably [shouldn't be used in the main thread](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop) due to their blocking nature, and won't be able to be used in the same thread that is trying to setup a timeout on their operation.

For example when creating the first promise for `Promise.race` in the code snippet -

```
 new Promise( (resolve, reject) => 
   resultset.toObjArray( ( _, rows) => resolve(rows) )
```

the promise executor is called synchronously and in turn calls `resultset.toObjArray` synchronously which, if blocking, stops the executor returning to the promise constructor before row data has been obtained. Setting up a call duration timeout afterwards would serve no purpose, and a callback from a timer set up beforehand can not be executed in the same thread while it is blocked.